# How to remove a tab from a tab pane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have created a swing application as bellow which shows main tasks in tabs when clicking the buttons which are related to specific tasks. I have added a small close button to each tab and what I need to to is close the tab when clicking the close button related to that tab.

[image]

The close button is in a class which is extended fron JPanel class as bellow,

```
public class CloseTab extends JPanel {

    JLabel title = new JLabel();
    JButton closeButton = new JButton();
    int tabIndex;
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = null;
    public static int SELECTED_TAB_INDEX;
    .
    .
    .    

    public static void setSELECTED_TAB_INDEX(int SELECTED_TAB_INDEX) {
        CloseTab.SELECTED_TAB_INDEX = SELECTED_TAB_INDEX;
    }

    .
    .

    public void setCloseAction(ActionListener al) {
        closeButton.addActionListener(al);
        closeButton.setSize(10, 10);
        closeButton.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
        closeButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/org/ofm/mnu/icons/delete.gif")));

    }

    public void setTabIndex(int index) {
        this.tabIndex = index;
        System.out.println(tabIndex);
    }

    public void init() {
        add(title);
        add(closeButton);
        setOpaque(false);
        setCloseAction(closeActoion);      

    }



    ActionListener closeActoion = new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // System.out.println(tabIndex);
            if(tabbedPane.getTabCount() != 0 && tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() == SELECTED_TAB_INDEX){
                tabbedPane.remove(SELECTED_TAB_INDEX);
            }   
        }
    };

}
```

and in the main frame I seted the SELECTED_TAB_INDEX variable as follow,

```
tbpWorkSpace.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                JTabbedPane a = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource();
                CloseTab pnl = new CloseTab();                
                pnl.setSELECTED_TAB_INDEX(a.getSelectedIndex());
            }
        });
```

but, I couldn't get the result I wanted please tell me is there any other way to achieve the result I want.

Comment: what exactly is the problem? simply set an action to the button which removes the tab from the tabbedPane ...

Comment: It seems like you are getting mixed in different tabbed pane instances. Is the variable  `a` in `stateChanged` method is same as `tabbedPane` variable in `CloseTab` class? If yes, then why not add changeListener to that tabbedPane?

Comment: >@Harry Joy - I think I've gone on a long and wrong path for the task I required, it seems your method is very correct. Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove tab use `.remove(index)` method of JTabbedPane. Learn more here: [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
private void removeTabWithTitle(String tabTitleToRemove) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tabbedPane.getTabCount(); i++) {
        String tabTitle = tabbedPane.getTitleAt(i);
        if (tabTitle.equals(tabTitleToRemove)) {
            tabbedPane.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```